# Shell exec less than symbol between vars

Tags: php, bash, shell

I'm using the following code in `shell_exec` in PHP:

`$shell_command  = "c:\php\php_cgi.exe c:\php\php_test.php";`

`$post_temp_path = "c:\php\temp.212";`

`shell_exec("$shell_command < $post_temp_path");`

I do not understand what the `<` between variables does. Can anyone explain what this symbol `<` does in the shell?

Comment: You should probably clarify exactly what you are asking. Technically your code would evaluate whether the value of `$shell_command` is less than the value of `$post_temp_path` and return a `boolean` value to `shell_exec` as an argument. Did you mean to ask about [I/O redirection in the Bash shell](http://www.tldp.org/LDP/abs/html/io-redirection.html) instead? Because that would have nothing to do with PHP and your code and tag are thus confusing.

Answer (score 0):

Your shell program (*such as the Bash shell, for example*) allows for something called *I/O redirection*. In your example, this basically means you take the *output* of one thing and direct it to the *input* of another thing.

The greater-than `>` operator redirects the output of `$shell_command` to the input of whatever `$post_temp_path` is (*in this case apparently a file*). The less-than `<` operator, would do the opposite (*for example, accept input to the command from the file*).

See [I/O Redirection](http://www.tldp.org/LDP/abs/html/io-redirection.html) for more details. **And yes, these same basic concepts can apply to the DOS-shell as well, perhaps forgoing some of the more advanced syntaxes outline in the Bash shell.**